# Misspelling on the Data StackExchange Help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, data-explorer

There is misspelling of the word "parameter" on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer Help Page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) website. Here is a snap shot wherein the misspelling is highlighted in orange:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops, good catch. [Taken care of](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/36), pending a pull and redeploy.

Comment: Wow. That's amazing! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: You might want to correct "robot menance" further down that page.

Comment: In fact I've just authored my first Pull Request fixing it.

Comment: Son of a...Thanks @Mark!